# 8 Queens Function problem - The placeQueen function doesn't execute ( backtracking )

Tags: c++, oop, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

everything works fine but my last function doesn't execute properly.
'''
//Safe check

```
bool Board::isSafe(int row, int col) {
   for (int i = 0; i < col ; i++)
      if (myBoard[row][i]==1)
         return false;
   for (int i=row, j=col; i>=0 && j>=0; i--, j--)
      if (myBoard[i][j]==1)
         return false;
   for (int i=row, j=col; j>=0 && i<8; i++, j--)
      if (myBoard[i][j]==1)
         return false;
   return true;
};
```

//Placing the Queens -> This function done work properly

```
 bool Board::placeQueen(int row, int col){
 if (col >= 8)
 {
      return true;
 }
 else {
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
       myBoard[i][col] = 1;
      if (isSafe(i,col)==true) {
          Board::placeQueen(row, col + 1);
        }
         myBoard[i][col] = 0;
       
      }
 }
   return false;
};
```

in the main, I do this `myBoard.placeQueen(0,0);` but everything on the board is Zero.

Comment: Two things I see that are odd. : 1. you're not reaping the results from your recursive calls at all. You simply recurse, ignore whether false or true was returned, then continue marching on in the for-loop. Failure to reap recursed results is probably *the* most common mistake made by people new or inexperienced with recursive algorithms.  2. the recursion arguments should be utilizing `i` but isn't. [Talk to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you please help me with some code regarding the recursion? I didn't fully understand

Answer (score 0):

**First issue**.  Your `IsSafe` function is scanning for queens on the same row and diagonals, but isn't checking for queens on the same column. And the diagonal checking looks suspicious.  It's scanning up/left and down/left, but it's not scanning up/right and down/right.

**Second issue**. Your `placeQueen` function is halting its recursion when `col == 8`, not necessarily when there are 8 queens placed on the board. Use another variable to keep track of how many queens are on the board. It can be a global or passed via recursion.

**Third issue**. Your `placeQueen` function is only incrementing the column variable, but never increments the row variable. I don't think it ever gets past row 0.

Those may not be your only bugs.

I'll provide more hints if you demonstrate more progress.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So my function checks the board Vertically, rather than Horizontally. That's why only checks the left side, up/left and down/left. and I increase the Row variable by (i), Basically, I don't need to increase row variable.